# input two user inputs to two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I want to take 2 inputs from the user, then I want to add them to the following 2 arrays. I tried this code but this is not doing the job correctly . What should I do

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
   
public class Input {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] runnersNames = {"Shiran", "Hasini", "Chanchala", "Priyankara", "Mayuri", "Sameera", "Supun"
                    , "Supuni", "Kavindu", "Nadeeka"};
        int[] minutes = {342, 448, 398, 399, 350, 321, 299, 378, 384, 440};
        System.out.println("Do you want to add more players? 1.Yes 2.No ");
        int n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("your choice : ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
    
        if (n == 1) {
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the player name : ");
                runnersNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
    
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the player runtime : ");
                    minutes[j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
    
    
            }
    
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of arrays (which are fixed size) you can use Lists ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the original names with newly added values inside the loop. Try not to start the loop from 0.
EDIT:-You may also need to use a 2D array/list for minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *add* players to the these two variable, you have two options:
Create an array with more space,
or using a different data structure, like a `List`.
First option (creating an array that has more space):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] runnersNames = {"Shiran", "Hasini", "Chanchala", "Priyankara", "Mayuri", "Sameera", "Supun"
                , "Supuni", "Kavindu", "Nadeeka","","","","","","","","","",""};
        int[] minutes = {342, 448, 398, 399, 350, 321, 299, 378, 384, 440,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
        System.out.println("Do you want to add more players? 1.Yes 2.No ");
        int n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("your choice : ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        
        if (n == 1) {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the player name : ");
                runnersNames[i+10] = sc.nextLine();

                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the player runtime : ");
                    minutes[j+10] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            
            }
        
        }
    
    }
}
```

The second option is a bit cleaner, I think:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> runnersNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Shiran", "Hasini", "Chanchala", "Priyankara", "Mayuri",
            "Sameera", "Supun", "Supuni", "Kavindu", "Nadeeka")});
        List<Integer> minutes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{342, 448, 398, 399, 350, 321, 299, 378, 384, 440}));
        System.out.println("Do you want to add more players? 1.Yes 2.No ");
        int n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("your choice : ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        
        if (n == 1) {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the player name : ");
                runnersNames.add(sc.nextLine());
                
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the player runtime : ");
                    minutes.add(sc.nextInt());
                }
            
            }
        
        }
    
    }
}
```

You can then get an element of the list using the `get(int index)` method.

```
minutes.get(0);
```